# Keep div (when expanded) in browser window view

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I have added this script to make sure `#myDiv` is fully in view when expanded:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollIntoView();
```

However, this sets the top of `#myDiv` to the top of the browser window. Is there a way to modify this, to make the bottom of `#myDiv` set a certain amount of pixels from the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: Can you create a snippet please?

Answer (score 0):

Element.scrollIntoView **cannot** do what you want.

Calculate the offset on your own with the document's scrollHeight (check compatibility) and the absolute offset of the element on the document  (usually recursive function using offsetTop on the element itself, its parentNode and so on)

I once read those articles:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to regard the element's outerHeight aswell :)